# Which is more expensive, buying house or condo?

Tags: house

Which is more expensive, buying house or condo?

House seems like but my lover told me that I have to pay tons of bills

So I considered changing to condo. Is condo more better than house or not?

Comment: This is realistically unanswerable.  Some houses will be less expensive than some condos.  Some condos will be less expensive than some houses.  There are different risks and benefits to each and different types of bills to pay for each.

Comment: Are you talking about the purchase price or the upkeep?

Comment: upkeep of bills etc @Manziel

Comment: Personal advice - be open about money with your partner, sooner than later. This will prevent buildup of financial stress on both sides. If you are asked to pay 1/2 of something if you live with someone, it is totally reasonable to ask to see those bills so you understand where the money is going.

Comment: Tell your lover that your money can't buy his/her love: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lTq0WLThOyY

Comment: Here are two similar questions to what you asked: What's more expensive, a laptop or a desktop? Which should I buy, a laptop or a desktop? (Hint: it depends on *many* factors.)

Answer (score 2):

Purchasing a condo typically requires input of monthly condo fees - these pay for things like common areas, perhaps security, perhaps some utilities, and likely some type of common repair fund for future maintenance. Purchase a 'freehold' unit [whether a house, or freehold townhouse, etc.], typically has no monthly maintenance fees, but the burden of performing those actions is on you.

ie: if you own a house, you have to perform yard maintenance or pay someone to do it, and if you're in a condo-townhouse, the condo board probably pays someone to do everyone's yards at the same time, and charges each unit for the expense.

In a case where you would otherwise pay someone to do it for your house, then a condo might be cheaper because a good condo board can achieve nice group rates for maintenance. As well, if you own a house you probably don't put money every year into a '20-year roof repair fund' [but this could be a good idea though most don't], so seeing the monthly condo fee going to future repairs can seem expensive but might just be the same cost you would otherwise pay, spread out over time instead of all at once when damage happens.

If your condo has amenities you do use, it might be cheaper than the alternative - ie: maybe your fee includes $50 for gym maintenance, and you would otherwise pay $75 for a gym membership, this portion saves you money.

If your condo has amenities you *don't* use, these fees can add up quickly - maybe $100 / month for pool maintenance, etc.

As to initial costs - costs per square foot of a condo are typically higher than an equivalent house in the same area, but given the size is smaller it might be cheaper in total, so you might have a smaller mortgage.

**All this depends on the specific unit, these are generalities**. A penthouse might cost $5M in a medium-sized city's downtown core, vs a house for $100k waaaaaaay out in a rural area past the suburbs.

Comment: Communities of single family and townhouses can have monthly fees in the hundreds. That community pool costs money. As does other common land that requires upkeep.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep Agreed - I am loosely using the term 'condo townhouse' to refer to such an arrangement, but it might also be known as a HOA etc.,; any body which has the legal right to demand payment to perform services can have such an impact [maybe worth it, maybe not, depending on how the board is run and whether you use services].